# What's the matter with "com.layer.atlas:layer-atlas"?

Tags: android, gradle, layer, atlas

Now I can't resolve the dependency, what's the matter? 
Is the company change the name ?But ,I see it in their web , without "com.layer.atlas:layer-atlas" ,however my app contains this dependency, anyone who can tell me why?

[image]

Comment: it's a very poor question, please try to clarify and ask a precise one. Strongly recommend reading [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: If you hover your mouse pointer over the highlighted part, it should tell you more in a pop-up.

Comment: @LazerBanana sorry , I am going to ask a good question ,thank you for point it out!

Comment: @jdv , Ok ,thanks for help !  I have solved it in a other way !

Answer (score 0):

Can you show us the gradle file? According to the Installation-Instructions on their [GitHub](https://github.com/layerhq/Atlas-Android) you will have to include their repositories like so

```
repositories {
    maven { url "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/layerhq/releases-android/master/releases/" }
    maven { url "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/layerhq/Atlas-Android/master/releases/" }
}
```

Comment: yeah, I get this , but ,it doesn't work, look my gradle file:repositories {
        maven{
            url 'http://maven.aliyun.com/nexus/content/groups/public/'
        }
        jcenter {
            url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/"
        }
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }
        maven {
            url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots'
        }
    }

Comment: and see this :   
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-nop:1.5.8'
    compile 'com.layer.atlas:layer-atlas:0.2.10'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.6'

Comment: @GojiSupport but according to your first comment you do not include the layerhq-entries as mentioned in my answer? Could you please update your question and post your entire build.gradle?

Comment: I've already tried it，but it's too long to be add . How can I send it to you?@Nikolas

Comment: According to their github their current version is 0.4.6, you're using 0.2.10. Maybe they removed their older artifacts? Maybe use the latest version?